# Show/Hide based on content within div

Tags: javascript, hide, show

I would like to show or hide a header element (e.g. `<h3></h3>`) based up a div tag that either contains content or not. The content is dynamically added, but the header element is static, which results in having the header element shown with no content below it many times. Here's an example:

```
<div id=related-section>
<h3>Related Articles</h3>
<div id=related>
<p>This content is being shown, sometimes it is not shown.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Further details:
There are two states for what `<div id=related>` looks like, it's either (for example) 1) `<div id=related><p>Prima insolens hendrerit his et, sit exerci detracto...</p></div>` or 2) `<div id=related></div>`. The latter showing that there's zero content inside the div.

Comment: can you provide some JS with this example?

Comment: Looks like this OP is a one and done'r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery you could do the following, after updating the contents of `#related`

```
if( $("#related *").length > 0 ) {
   $("#related-section h3").show();
} else {
   $("#related-section h3").hide();
}
```

But if it is the full code you provided you could also hide / show the whole div `#related-section` because it has no other visible content then.

Answer (score 1):

Created a fiddle for you with the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/2vJfN/

Comment: +1 this works although only plain text is withing `#related` in opposite to my answer.

Comment: @DanielB: Thanks!  Updated my fiddle to check length as well.  Good points.

Comment: Hi Pixelbobby, I tested out this script on IE7/8, and it throws an error, "Object doesn't support the property or method". Still works fine on all browsers, but want to avoid seeing the error in IE. Thanks.